# VBA 64 Bit Forms Image Control and loading an image from byte array

Tags: vba, image, ms-access, winapi, 64-bit

I have an Access 365 64-bit problem I am trying to solve and I need some guidance.

I have a byte array with image data, retrieved from a Base64 encoded string. The decoding is working just fine and I can produce the array as expected. I have had this code from an older 32 bit version of VBA applications and it remains fully functional. So far so good.

The issue comes into play when I am trying to place the image data into a forms image control directly - no saving to a file. I have had this working in the 32 bit applications but now that the office 365 subscription I am working with is 64 bit (as is the rest of the company) I am having trouble converting the API calls and subsequent code across to 64-bit compatible versions. The images are largely PNG and JPG images (when extracted).

The main issue seems to be coming from the need to replace OLEPRO32 with OLEAUT32. The code runs (seemingly) without error however I am not getting any output. I am sure that I am missing something simple but I just cannot see it. My code is below as well as the API declarations I am using, along with the old OLEPRO32 declaration which is commented out.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

Declare PtrSafe Function CreateStreamOnHGlobal Lib "ole32" (ByVal hGlobal As LongPtr, ByVal fDeleteOnRelease As Long, ppstm As Any) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal uFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
'Declare PtrSafe Function OleLoadPicture Lib "olepro32" (pStream As Any, ByVal lSize As Long, ByVal fRunmode As Long, riid As Any, ppvObj As Any) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function OleLoadPicture Lib "oleaut32" (pStream As Any, ByVal lSize As Long, ByVal fRunmode As Long, riid As Any, ppvObj As Any) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
```

And here is the routine that uses the declarations:

```
Public Function ArrayToPicture(inArray() As Byte, Offset As Long, Size As Long) As IPicture

    ' function creates a stdPicture from the passed array
    ' Offset is first item in array: 0 for 0 bound arrays
    ' Size is how many bytes comprise the image
    Dim o_hMem  As LongPtr
    Dim o_lpMem  As LongPtr
    Dim aGUID(0 To 3) As Long
    Dim IIStream As IUnknown

    aGUID(0) = &H7BF80980    ' GUID for stdPicture
    aGUID(1) = &H101ABF32
    aGUID(2) = &HAA00BB8B
    aGUID(3) = &HAB0C3000

    o_hMem = GlobalAlloc(&H2&, Size)
    If Not o_hMem = 0& Then
        o_lpMem = GlobalLock(o_hMem)
        If Not o_lpMem = 0& Then
            CopyMemory ByVal o_lpMem, inArray(Offset), Size
            Call GlobalUnlock(o_hMem)
            If CreateStreamOnHGlobal(o_hMem, 1&, IIStream) = 0& Then
                  Call OleLoadPicture(ByVal ObjPtr(IIStream), 0&, 0&, aGUID(0), ArrayToPicture)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

If anyone has any ideas please let me know. The output of this function seems to be nothing at all whereas in the past I could expect a valid iPicture object that could be assigned directly to the form image controls .PictureData.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Cheers

The Frog

UPDATE:

I have worked through a large portion of the code and can now specifically isolate the locations where the crashes are happening. Code is below

```
Option Compare Database

' API declarations


Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateStreamOnHGlobal Lib "Ole32.dll" (ByRef hGlobal As LongPtr, ByVal fDeleteOnRelease As Long, ByRef ppstm As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CLSIDFromString Lib "Ole32" (ByVal lpsz As LongPtr, pclsid As Any) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function OLELoadPicture Lib "OleAut32.lib" (ByRef lpStream As LongPtr, ByVal lSize As Long, ByVal fRunMode As Long, ByRef RIID As GUID, ByRef lplpObj As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetObject Lib "gdi32" Alias "GetObjectA" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr, ByVal nCount As Long, lpObject As Any) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDIBits Lib "gdi32" (ByVal aHDC As LongPtr, ByVal hBitmap As LongPtr, ByVal nStartScan As Long, ByVal nNumScans As Long, lpBits As Any, lpBI As BITMAPINFO, ByVal wUsage As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub MoveMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)

'Necessary Types
Private Type BITMAPINFOHEADER '40 Bytes
    biSize As Long
    biWidth As Long
    biHeight As Long
    biPlanes As Integer
    biBitCount As Integer
    biCompression As Long
    biSizeImage As Long
    biXPelsPerMeter As Long
    biYPelsPerMeter As Long
    biClrUsed As Long
    biClrImportant As Long
End Type

Private Type RGBQUAD
    rgbBlue As Byte
    rgbGreen As Byte
    rgbRed As Byte
    rgbReserved As Byte
End Type

Private Type BITMAPINFO
    bmiHeader As BITMAPINFOHEADER
    bmiColors As RGBQUAD
End Type

Private Type DIBHEADER '14 magical bytes
    BmpIdentification(1) As Byte
    BmpSize(3) As Byte
    BmpCreator As Integer
    BmpCreator2 As Integer
    BmpDataOffset(3) As Byte
End Type
Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type


Public Function StdPictureToDibImage(ByRef Picture As StdPicture, Optional PadColor As Integer = -1) As Byte()
    ' Performs StdPicture to DIB compliant Byte Array
    ' Adopted based on : http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?833125-How-to-convert-StdPicture-into-pixel-array
    
    ' The Byte Arrays to Hold the Initial PictureData along with the Final One
    Dim ImageData() As Byte
    Dim buffer() As Byte
    Dim tmp() As Byte
    ' Type Instances
    Dim BMI As BITMAPINFO
    Dim DIB As DIBHEADER
    Dim PaddingColor As Integer
    ' API handle
    Dim hdc As LongPtr
    Dim hpic As LongPtr
    
    hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(0) 'Create a temporary in-memory device context
    BMI.bmiHeader.biSize = Len(BMI.bmiHeader) 'Initialize BitmapInfoHeader with header size
    
    'Get the header Info of the Image based on the StdPicture handle provided
    GetDIBits hdc, Picture.handle, 0, 0, ByVal 0&, BMI, 0 'Get Information about the image
    
    'Normally here we would setup the header for BMI header but i found out that simply is not working as it should
    ' Only the DIB header needs manual handling
    
    With DIB
        .BmpIdentification(0) = 66
        .BmpIdentification(1) = 77
        tmp = LongToByteArray(BMI.bmiHeader.biSizeImage + Len(DIB) + Len(BMI.bmiHeader))
         .BmpSize(0) = tmp(0)
         .BmpSize(1) = tmp(1)
         .BmpSize(2) = tmp(2)
         .BmpSize(3) = tmp(3)
        .BmpCreator = 0
        .BmpCreator2 = 0
        tmp = LongToByteArray(Len(DIB) + Len(BMI.bmiHeader))
        .BmpDataOffset(0) = tmp(0)
         .BmpDataOffset(1) = tmp(1)
         .BmpDataOffset(2) = tmp(2)
         .BmpDataOffset(3) = tmp(3)
    End With
    'Byte Arrays Initialization
    
    ReDim ImageData(3, BMI.bmiHeader.biWidth - 1, BMI.bmiHeader.biHeight - 1)  'Initialize array for holding pixel data
    ReDim buffer(0 To BMI.bmiHeader.biSizeImage + (Len(DIB) + Len(BMI.bmiHeader)) - 1)
    
    'Here we get the actual Image Data from the StdPicture
    'This was the most troubled part of the whole process as it kept truncating the image to around 3/4
    ' no matter what....until i noticed that the info "feeded" to the BMI header was wrong
    
    hpic = CLngPtr(Picture.handle)
    GetDIBits hdc, hpic, 0, Abs(BMI.bmiHeader.biHeight), ImageData(0, 0, 0), BMI, 0 'Get pixel data
    
    'GetDIBits hdc, Picture.handle, 0, Abs(BMI.bmiHeader.biHeight), ImageData(0, 0, 0), BMI, 0 'Get pixel data
    
    'Constructing the Final Image Data
    '1st the DIB header ***** CRUCIAL ******* , without this everything fails and burns
    CopyMemory buffer(0), DIB, Len(DIB)
    '2nd the BMP header, this was done in all other cases
    CopyMemory buffer(Len(DIB)), BMI.bmiHeader, Len(BMI.bmiHeader)
    '3rd the actual image data
    CopyMemory buffer(Len(DIB) + Len(BMI.bmiHeader)), ImageData(0, 0, 0), 3 * (BMI.bmiHeader.biWidth - 1) * (BMI.bmiHeader.biHeight - 1)
  
    'Cleaning up
    DeleteDC hdc 'Get rid of temporary in-memory device context
    'Some Padding to remove the "dead" space because Images Dimensions are "resized" to multiple of 4s
    'so if the either of the dimensions is not exactly a multiple of 4 then padding is applied which
    'results is "dead" pixels
    If PadColor < 0 Then
    PaddingColor = 255
    Else
    PaddingColor = PadColor
    End If
    For I = UBound(buffer) To LBound(buffer) Step -1
    If buffer(I) = 0 Then
    buffer(I) = PaddingColor
    Else
    Exit For
    End If
    Next
    'The final magical byte array...no more temp files,links,extra controls...whatever..everything in memory
    StdPictureToDibImage = buffer()
End Function

Public Function PictureFromByteStream(ByRef B() As Byte) As IPicture
Dim LowerBound As Long
Dim ByteCount As Long
Dim hMem As Long
Dim lpMem As Long
Dim IID_IPicture As GUID
Dim istm As stdole.IUnknown

On Error GoTo Err_Init
If UBound(B, 1) < 0 Then
Exit Function
End If

LowerBound = LBound(B)
ByteCount = (UBound(B) - LowerBound) + 1

hMem = GlobalAlloc(&H2, ByteCount)
If hMem <> 0 Then
    lpMem = GlobalLock(hMem)
    If lpMem <> 0 Then
        MoveMemory ByVal lpMem, B(LowerBound), ByteCount
        Call GlobalUnlock(hMem)
        If CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hMem, 1, istm) = 0 Then
            If CLSIDFromString(StrPtr("{7BF80980-BF32-101A-8BBB-00AA00300CAB}"), IID_IPicture) = 0 Then
                Call OLELoadPicture(ByVal ObjPtr(istm), ByteCount, 0, IID_IPicture, PictureFromByteStream)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

Exit Function

Err_Init:
If err.Number = 9 Then
Debug.Print err.Number & " - " & err.Description
End Function

Function ArrayToStdPicture(imageBytes() As Byte) As StdPicture

Dim W As WIA.Vector
Dim s As StdPicture

Set W = New WIA.Vector
W.BinaryData = imageBytes

Set ArrayToStdPicture = W.Picture

If Not W Is Nothing Then Set W = Nothing
End Function
```

The process is as follows:

ArrayToStdPicture -> StdPictureToDIBImage

The crash occurs on the line:

```
GetDIBits hdc, hpic, 0, Abs(BMI.bmiHeader.biHeight), ImageData(0, 0, 0), BMI, 0 'Get pixel data
```

The crash totally crashes MS Access and kills the application.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but HRESULT is not a LongPtr, it's a 32 bits => Long. What do you get from OleLoadPicture call? Is there an error code?

Comment: No error codes are showing up at all.

I thought I'd try another approach using Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) and am encountering an error code that way too - but at least it's a code that provides some info. I am not used to working with WIA and I am not seeming to find a way to solve this.

WIA basic process is this:
- Load WIA Vector object with the byte array using BinaryData field
- Convert to BMP using WIA ImageProcess

Getting error that the STDPicture object I am returning in not a device-independent bitmap (DIB). Any ideas?

Comment: A little more research here and I have discovered that the oleloadpicture call is not liking the function name as the last parameter.